# Is "Giftwish" this novel?

Tags: story-identification, novel, languages, magical-items

When I was younger (in the 80's) I greatly enjoyed a book that I believe was called *Giftwish*.  There is a fantasy book by the same name referenced here, https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1316830.Giftwish, but the details in the reviews don't match my memories.

The main element I remember is a magic sword (which I think was called "Giftwish") that could be used to open a door leading into a castle built in another world.  There was also a lot in the book about a "true language of power" that was based on Latin.

The reviews cited above reference a fantasy land called Feydom, a faked-up prophecy and a Necromancer, none of which I remember.

Are these two the same book?  Are there two books by the same name?  Or am I remembering another book by the wrong title?

Comment: [review](https://goo.gl/ZRUkAg) *"It starts with this hapless boy who goes to the big city to sell the crops of his parents' farm, but along the way he meets all these strange people who for some reason insist on dressing him up a certain way and giving him a goat... he thinks nothing of it, but when he gets to the city the mayor declares that he is the Chosen One because it was prophecised that at market day a young boy with a feather in his hat and a goat would come and rescue them all... by going on something akin to a suicide mission.*

Comment: *I can't describe it well but the gist of it was that the town dressed him up to be this prophecised kid and really majorly screwed him over. And he had no chance but to get out there and try and become the hero they wanted him to be. It was excellent. The book was called "Giftwish" by Graham Dunstan Martin."*

Comment: @Richard Well, that at least references the "magic sword" aspect.  The other details are pretty identical to the reviews I've already seen elsewhere.  It does sound more and more like this is the same book.  You would think I'd remember all the bit about the prophecy, but maybe that part wasn't as cool to me as a kid.

Comment: Yeah, I can definitely confirm that Giftwish is a sword.  If you go to Google Books and search for "giftwish sword" there's a bunch of books with capsule reviews of Giftwish that refer to the sword.  They don't go into the plot enough to answer the OP's other questions, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has [already been answered](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/99263/23243) with that this is the same novel, but I might as well provide a few additional details.

The titular sword Giftwish was crafted by the ancestor of the Necromancer and one of its powers is that it can open the gate of the Necromancer's castle. The Necromancer's castle is under a different spell that puts it between the world of Feydom and another world, which makes it invulnerable or some such thing, and makes it travel from one world to the other with the night-day cycle.

Comment: Thanks, that's the detail that cinches it!  That's the part that was really memorable to me that wasn't mentioned in any of the other descriptions.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like it to me; there's also a sequel, *[Catchfire](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1316827.Catchfire)*. I definitely remember them talking about using Latin, as to them it was a 'future' language that no-one else used. It's by Graham D. Martin.

> A peasant lad from the coast of Feydom, said to fulfill an ancient prophecy but really intended to be a sacrificial victim, travels to the mountains where he confronts the Necromancer, the shadow of evil
>
> <sub>-- [Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Giftwish.html?id=5MiKHAAACAAJ&redir_esc=y)</sub>

Comment: Do you happen to remember if the sword opens a door to a castle built in another world? As Chris stated, he doesn't remember there being a necromancer or a land named Feydom in the book he's speaking of.

Comment: The detail about Latin being a "future" language sounds right, and it's quite possible I just don't remember the other parts.  But, as Sean mentioned, my main question is whether this is the book with the magic sword and the castle.